# Rails 4.0 Engine and nested Routing testing with Rspec 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rspec3

I have written an engine:

```
module MercatorMpay24
  class Admin::PaymentsController < ::Admin::AdminSiteController
    def check_confirmation
      @payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

and defined a route:

```
MercatorMpay24::Engine.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    get 'payments/:id/check_confirmation' => 'payments#check_confirmation', 
        :as => 'check_confirmation'
  end
end
```

that works fine and can be called, responds, ...

Now I want to unit test that:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe MercatorMpay24::Admin::PaymentsController, :type => :controller do
  describe "GET #check_confirmation" do
    it "finds the payment" do
      @payment = create(:payment)
      get :check_confirmation, id: @payment.id
      expect(assigns(:payment)).to eql @payment
    end
  end
end
```

but that gives me an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"check_confirmation",
:controller=>"mercator_mpay24/admin/payments", :id=>"1"}
```

while `rake routes | grep check_confirmation` gives me:

```
admin_check_confirmation GET  /admin/payments/:id/check_confirmation(.:format) 
mercator_mpay24/admin/payments#check_confirmation
```

I guess, I'm doing something wrong with namespaces here, but I have no clue, what ....

Answer (score 0):

I was missing:

```
routes { MercatorMpay24::Engine.routes }
```

in the controller spec.